# Algolia highlighting objectID using autocomplete.js

Tags: javascript, algolia

The `_highlightResult` object returned does not contain the `ID` or `objectID`. Is it possible to get it returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer on the [Algolia forums](https://discourse.algolia.com/t/highlighting-the-objectid/1452)

> If you really need to search and highlight the object ID, we encourage you to duplicate its value to another attribute, and include that attribute in `searchableAttributes` and `attributesToHighlight`.